# how to read back an xml file saved with NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of my own class:

```
var listofmyclasses = [MyClass]()
```

in MyClass I have implemented:

```
 - func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!)
 - init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
```

I am writing an XML File with the content of my array and this works fine:

```
         let plistpath = directories[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("BookmarkArray.plist")
         let archivedData = NSMutableData()
         let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: archivedData)
         archiver.outputFormat = NSPropertyListFormat.XMLFormat_v1_0
         archiver.encodeObject(listofbookmarks)
         archiver.finishEncoding()
         archivedData.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: true)
```

The File is saved in XML format. Great !

Now the question:

How to read the content of the XML back to a new array of MyClass ?:

```
var newArray:[MyClass]=getContent(plistpath);
```

What I tried so far:

```
var archivedData2:NSMutableData = NSMutableData(contentsOfFile: plistpath)!;
let listofmyclasses2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archivedData2);
```

but listofmyclasses2 is nil.

Comment: Use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` class for that.

Comment: I updated with trying to use NSKeyedUnarchiver. I don't understand how to use this class and I do not find any sources on this. Any help ?

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/ this site will show you how to use nskeyedunarchiver

Comment: Mentoined page explains how to use unarchiveObjectWithFile (which is not used in my code) and NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile. With mentoined methods I already persisted and restored data successfully, but I liked to have the format readable like XML. I can also live with this, but I thought someone could help restoring the data, which I started to store:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to read back the file:

```
    let dat : NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(plistpath) as NSData
    let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: dat)
    let read_bookmarks = unarchiver.decodeObject() as [MyClass]
    unarchiver.finishDecoding()
```

(Of course you certainly want to use better error checking :-) )

Answer (score 0):

The class `NSPropertyListSerialization` can decode all sorts of plist encodings like `NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0`

```
NSError* error;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
NSDictionary* dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&error];
```